# Don't know where to display my change() event

Tags: jquery, function, triggers, drop-down-menu

I have been struggling for hours to input this change event to exexcute in my jquery. How can I input this change event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#optionDropId").change();
});
```

into the code below:

```
$("#optionDropId").change(function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $("#numberDropId").html("");
    $.each(OptDrop[selectedValue], function(x,y){
        $("#numberDropId").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", y).html(y));
    });

});
```

If anyone knows this would be a big help. Thank You

Comment: Show your HTML and then explain what's supposed to happen when something (and which element) changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to bind the handler to the event BEFORE you can call it:

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#optionDropId").change(function ()
        {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            $("#numberDropId").html("");
            $.each(OptDrop[selectedValue], function (x, y)
            {
                $("#numberDropId").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", y).html(y));
            });
        }); 

        $("#optionDropId").change();
    });
```

Comment: thank you, that is what I meant, binding the function and the change() event together. Thank You :)